# iOS - object sent autorelease too many times

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, ios4

I have a method that is reading some information from a sqlite db and initialising a class called Achievement.  When I analyse this code I am given the feedback 'object sent autorelease too many times'.  I don't really understand where I am going wrong - why is the retval object released on line 225 and not at the return statement on line 229?

Can someone please explain where I have made a mistake in the code below and how I can fix it?

Function Code (so answerer can easily copy/paste):

```
- (Achievement *)getAchievement:(int)Id
```

{

```
Achievement *retval = [[Achievement alloc] autorelease];

NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Achievements where ID = %d", Id];

sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)
    == SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        int Id = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        char *name = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        char *title  = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
        char *description = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);

        Boolean Achieved;
        char *com = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4);
        NSString *c1 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:com] autorelease];
        Achieved = [c1 isEqualToString:@"1"];

        NSDate *CompletedDate = (NSDate *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5);

        char *icon = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6);

        int New = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 7);

        NSString *Title = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:title] autorelease];
        NSString *Description = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:description] autorelease];
        NSString *Name = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:name] autorelease];
        NSString *Icon = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:icon] autorelease];

        retval = [retval initDetails:Id :Name :Title: Description : Achieved : CompletedDate: Icon: New];
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
return retval;
```

}

Analysis feedback image:
[image]

As always any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Achievement *retval = [[Achievement alloc] autorelease];
```

this is very bad idea to do that. You ALWAYS have to initialize object before using it.
Instead you're initializing it in a loop:

```
retval = [retval initDetails:Id :Name :Title: Description : Achieved : CompletedDate: Icon: New];
```

I don't really get why you need to initialize the same object multiple times. Maybe, you need to create multiple objects and init them with different values?

Rearrange this:

```
Achievement *retval = nil;
while (...) {
    [retval release];
    retval = [[Achievement alloc] initDetails: ...];
}
return [retval autorelease];
```

Comment: thanks Max, the while will only ever be iterated over once (the SQL will only ever return one row).  I initialise it in the loop because the values returned from the db call are available there.  How do you suggest I rearrange the function?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're confusing the compiler with the wrong sequence of `alloc`, `init`, `autorelease`. What you should be doing instead is the following (pseudocode):

```
Achievement *retval = nil;
while (...) {
    retval = [[[Achievement alloc] initDetails: ...] autorelease];
}
return retval;
```

Comment: ahhh, penny drop moment.  Thanks.